# Measure of the angle in an quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let  $ABCD$   an  convex  quadrilateral  and  $M$  the  midpoint of  $BC$. Find the measure of   the  angle ${BAD}$  if  $MA$ is  perpendicular on  $MD$, $m(\hat{ADM}) = 15^\circ$ and $ AB + CD = AD$. I  try  to   find  an  synthetic   solutions  but  I  don't  know   what is  the  construction  what  I  must  to  do.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $150^\circ$ I think (Since I don't know any tools for drawing geometric structures, I made this one by using paint, sorry for the bad formatting). In case the picture is not seen, I am writing the solution here:

Let $|AB| = 2a$, $|CD| = 2b$ and $P$ be the midpoint of $[AD]$. Then $|MA| = |MP| = |MD|$ because $m(\widehat{AMD}) = 90^\circ$. Then notice that $|MP| = \frac{|AB|+|CD|}{2}$. With that equality and $|BM| = |MC|$, $|AP| = |PD|$, we can say that $[MP]$ is a mid segment. Therefore $[AB]$ // $[MP]$ // $[CD]$. Rest is obvious.
[image: Here]